# How to use .def files to create forwarded exports in a Rust dll (cdylib)

Tags: rust, dll, linker

I'm trying to add a forwarded exported function on my Rust crate by passing a .def file to the MSVC linker. I've created the following simple .def file:

```rust
EXPORTS
   ExportName=ForwardedModule.ExportName
```

Then, I've added the following content to my `.cargo\config` file:

```rust
[build]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=/DEF:C:\\Path\\To\\My\\DefFile\\file.def",
]
```

As far as I understand, this should be enough to create the forwarded exported entry on the resulting dll. However, the linker is throwing the following error:
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ExportName`.

The crate is defined as `crate-type = ["cdylib"]` in `cargo.toml`.

I've also tried adding the following code in `lib.rs`, but It didn't work either:

```rust
extern "C"
{
    #[no_mangle]
    fn ExportName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Two more steps were required.
First, I needed to declare the `ExportName` function as follows:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
fn ExportName() {
}
```

Then, I needed to set the target toolchain in the `.cargo\config` file:

```rust
[build]
target = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc"
rustflags = [
 "-C", "link-arg=/DEF:/DEF:C:\\Path\\To\\My\\DefFile\\file.def",
]
```

Comment: It probably should be `extern "C"`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I thought that as well, but It didn't work with `extern "C"`.